# Reason to use the NULL constraint when creating a table?

Tags: sql

It's my understanding that the following two code blocks are logically equivalent:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(Key INT PRIMARY KEY, Value INT NULL)

CREATE TABLE MyTable(Key INT PRIMARY KEY, Value INT)
```

Is there ever a time that you'd want to use the NULL constraint? Does it ever add anything?

Comment: Two cases come to mind: 1) Converting a `NOT NULL` field back to a `NULL`able field and 2) Just to be explicit about the column definitions.

Comment: The default nullability is nullable, so adding `NULL` is usually redundant.  You may wish to add it to be explicit in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

when you want insert into table you should assign value to all columns if not use NULL, but if a column has default value or NULL (which is a kind of default value) you can ignore that column.for example :

```
insert into MyTable (key) values (1)
```

if you don't use `Null` for `value` the above query occurred error. but if you add Null in definition the bellow result will add to database:

```
1,NULL
```

Comment: You don't need to add definition in table for default `null`. Have you tried what you're saying?

Comment: yes. if you don't add default value (such as null , etc.) you should add that field in  every insert/update query.

Comment: It works fine in `MsSql` for me, and I don't find any problem for that, Answer specifically where you've tried that

Comment: can you export your table definition? @Shahjahan

Comment: I've created table with this command `CREATE TABLE MyTable([Key] INT PRIMARY KEY, Value INT)` and insert value using your command `INSERT INTO MyTable ([Key]) VALUES(1)`. All works fine. The thing is when you haven't added `null` to your definition it'll automatically add `null` to your field. That's why i'm concerned with your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
     Key INT PRIMARY KEY, 
     Value INT NULL
)
```

In this block, you are instructing the SQL Engine that in case there is no value provided for the `Value column`, use a `default` assignment of `NULL`. This can be very well replaced by any other default value which is not NULL and holds a meaning that developers can troubleshoot or business groups understand

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
     Key INT PRIMARY KEY, 
     Value INT
)
```

In this block, you are instructing the SQL engine, that the application or user will definitely provide a value or an assignment for the value column. The code will error out if no default value (or actual value) is provided in place.

Comment: Is this true? I was under the impression that fields were billable (could contain a null value) by default.

Comment: @Dacromir: it might depend on the actual RDBMS engine you're using - but as far as I know, and for all the RDBMS I'm familiar with, you're right and Raunak is **wrong** - in this case, both `CREATE TABLE` statements are identical and provide the same table structure - a `Key` primary key (which is by definition `NOT NULL`), and a **nullable** `Value` column

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` constraint is the default when you define a column.  As you say, your two versions are equivalent, because SQL defines them to be equivalent.  Expressing an explicit `NULL` constraint is pretty much the same things as saying `INNER JOIN` rather than `JOIN` or including `ELSE NULL` in a `CASE` expression.

SQL is not a minimalist language.  There are multiple ways to express exactly the same thing.

In this case, I think `NULL` is included for two reasons:

- To be parallel to the `NOT NULL` constraint.
- If you can explicitly specify one, you should be able to explicitly specify the other.  Some users of databases might want to be explicit about NULL-able columns.

That said, I would say that most database designers leave it out.